# Bluetooth audio is spontaneously switching between codecs in 10.12.2

Tags: audio, macos, bluetooth

I use aptX capable Bluetooth headphones with a 2014 MacBook Pro. Since the Sierra 10.12.2 update, Bluetooth audio behaves in a weird way.

When the headphones connect, quality is first good.  Then in a few seconds it becomes horrendous.  After 5 seconds or so it recovers again.  After that it is fine until the next time the connection is made.

I can see the audio codec that is in use by Option-clicking the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. I can see that it starts out with aptX, then switches to SCO, then switches back to aptX.

Did anyone encounter this problem?  Is there a fix for it?  It is not a critical problem, but it is annoying.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.theghostbit.com/2015/03/force-mac-os-x-to-use-aptx-with-your.html) about forcing macOS to use aptX with your device.  I'm not sure it will help but there's a lot of other sites that link to it.